# Spring boot - save non-id field depending on id field while saving object

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an auto increment id field in spring boot class:

```
private long id //or it can be int, does not matter
```

I have also another field, which must be unique and alphanumeric, in same class:

```
private String code;
```

This field will have 6 alphanumeric (upper or lower case does not matter).

Is it possible to save this field auto while a new object created for that class, with such a method?

```
Long.toString("id_field_value",36);
```

Actually, it gives:

```
0 -> 0
1 -> 1
10 -> A
```

So, when first object is created, id will be 1.

Any suggestion?

For example, when i save `Person` object,

the `id` will be 1 automatically with JPA - hibarnate.

And also i want another field to be saved automatically, which is depending on `id` field.

So, id is 1, that `string code` must be 1 also.

Should i do this after  creating object ? Like:

Person person = personRepository.save(person3);
person.setCode(person.getId().toString);//or another functions

Comment: Apart form appearing completely pointless, you need to clarify what it is you want to do.You state *this field will have 6 alphanumeric (upper or lower case does not matter)*  but also when *string code must be 1 also*. So what is it 1 char or 6 chars. Why do you specify 36 as an arg. What are you expecting that to do?

Comment: I need another unique field. It must be alphanumeric. 26 capital letters + 10 numbers make 36 so i thought it will be best. E2E user will see this code on the UI and also we are using that field in some codes @AlanHay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `@PostPersist` annotation. You will have an id in your entity as soon as it is persisted. Something like:

```
@PostPersist
private void postPersist() {
    this.setCode( generateMyCode( getId() ) );
}
```

This works fine as long as `EntityManager` is used, the field code should also be persisted to the db.

When using Spring repositories it might be needed to perform extra `save()` (I do not have to, having just default config) after initial save but you should test this approach with your configuration.

*(Spring repositories handle persistence context a bit different way compared to the JPA standard usage with `EntityManager`.)*

Comment: `EntityManager` is not default? I tried and this `postpersist` worked.

Comment: @asdasasd Default was a bit bad wording. Repository uses em but not in 'default mode' it starts transaction. When you just inject em all changes to managed entities propagate to db without `persist()` or `save()`. But with repositories - with default settings - you always need to call `save(..)`. And `postPersist()` might work differently depending on the settings.

Comment: yes, i always use `repository.save` . So, with `postpersist` it wont be problem?

Comment: Should not be a problem. I'm just unable to find documentation & proof about how Spring data actually handles this case.

Comment: But my method is in another class.I need its is instance to call that method. How can i do this? I can initialize it in constructor.

Comment: @asdasasd You could make method static, inject it if possible to make it bean, or instantiate with new() when yoou need it. But I recommend you to do prepare a separate question considering that it is more helpful then to others also.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the `code` column you want is just exactly the `id` column but with another encoding (base 36 rather than base 10).

You don't need to store it, nor use a persistence annotation for that :

- For reading the code : on the entity, just add a getter method `getCode()` that compute it based on the `id` value.
- For searching by code, just convert the code from base 36 to base 10, then search by id.